# weird function behavious python

Tags: python

I have a text file called "PERFORMANCE" which includes lists of tests and their running time. example:

```
274x_reinput_raw_data run 9 sec
B-03507_add_pad_stack_with_rotation.csh run 8 sec
B-04869_board_copper.csh run 1 sec
```

I want to create a function name "get running time" that returns the running time of a given test.
I have created this function:

```
def get_running_time(test):
    running_time = 0
    line = PERFORMANCE_FILE.readline()
    while line != "":
        line_split = line.split()
        if test in line_split:
            running_time = line_split[-2]
        else:
            line = PERFORMANCE_FILE.readline()
    return running_time
```

but when i call:

```
 for test in failed_tests:
     file.write(str(get_running_time(test))+",")
```

it writes None.
Using prints in the middle i saw that the function takes one test name, searches for it but then does not move on to the next test.
I dont know where my mistake is. I tried many different things to no avail. I would love to get some help.
Thanks.

EDIT-
I have used prints to show an example:

```
def get_running_time(test):
    print(test)
    running_time = 0
    line = PERFORMANCE_FILE.readline()
    print(line)
    while line != "":
        line_split = line.split()
        print(line_split)
        if test in line_split:
            running_time = line_split[-2]
            print(running_time)
        else:
            line = PERFORMANCE_FILE.readline()
            print(line)
    return running_time
```

and the output in the console is:

```
DrillCleanup_unit_test.csh
274x_reinput_raw_data run 9 sec

['274x_reinput_raw_data', 'run', '9', 'sec']
B-03507_add_pad_stack_with_rotation.csh run 8 sec

['B-03507_add_pad_stack_with_rotation.csh', 'run', '8', 'sec']
B-04869_board_copper.csh run 1 sec

['B-04869_board_copper.csh', 'run', '1', 'sec']
B-04877_selftest_slot_histogram.csh run 0 sec

['B-04877_selftest_slot_histogram.csh', 'run', '0', 'sec']
B-06589_clipAreaRegressionTest run 8 sec


Nomenclature_unit_test.csh

PlaneClearance_unit_test.csh

SurfaceAnalyzer_unit_test.csh

274x_reinput_raw_data

B-03507_add_pad_stack_with_rotation.csh


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Why `while line != "":`? And what is test in `if test in line_split`?

Comment: what is the value of `test`??

Comment: `get_running_time` cannot return `None` with this indentation

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: line = "" means i got to end of file. test is the test name so if it is in the line it means found the line where i want to take the running time from.

Comment: @blue_note test name

Comment: Can you post the value of `test` as well?

Comment: no, the values you give to the variable `test`

Comment: @blue_note I edit the post and added prints

Comment: @ThatBird yes i added prints

Comment: @Adamso your description of the problem doesn't really match your code - as Jean-François Fabre mentions, your code snippet can NOT "return None" with this indentation (it can goes in an infinite loop but that's another problem). Please check your code for indentation mismatch (tabs / spaces mix - you can use tabnanny for this) and post the REAL code.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to search a specific line in a file is not your `while...if...else` that is likely to give an endless loop but a `for line in...if...break` construct. And you should reopen the file on each call, or at least rewind it, or make `PERFORMANCE_FILE` a list of lines to be able to scan the file more than once.

```
def get_running_time(test):
    for line in PERFORMANCE_FILE:
        line_split = line.split()
        if test in line_split:
            return line_split[-2]
    return 0
```

Comment: Still horrible performance.  Polynomial, where it could be linear.

Comment: @GeoffLentsch yes one could just build a mapping of `test_name:running_time` once for all - but first make it work, then - if needed - make it fast <g>

Answer (score 0):

```
while line != "":
    if test in line_split:
        running_time = line_split[-2]
    else:
        line = PERFORMANCE_FILE.readline()
```

Will hang, as this is forever loop. need to either break from the loop or read new line;

Might do something like:

```
while line != "":
    if test in line_split:
        running_time = line_split[-2]
    line = PERFORMANCE_FILE.readline()
```

Comment: I dont have an infinite loop because at some point i reach end of file

Comment: Yyou would have an infinite loop if test was found in line_split.  If test was in line_split, it will always be true.  This data is not being changed in this loop.

Comment: @Adamso if you don't have an infinite loop when `test` is found in `line_split` then the code you posted is NOT the code you execute, period.